# Submitting PHP form after http post in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate a bank payment solution to my angularJS app.

By default the bank solution comes with a PHP document that includes a form. I've managed to make a http.post call from my angularJS app including the total price of the order, but the PHP document returns the form instead of submitting it.

I'm not good at all with PHP, I'm sure I'm missing something super basic but I don't see what.

Here's my http call:

```
$scope.sabadell = function(){
  $scope.pago = {
    'total':$scope.total
  }
  var $promise=$http.post('sabadell/pago.php',$scope.pago); 

  $promise.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

And the PHP doc:

```
<?php

    $contentType = explode(';', $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']); 
    $rawBody = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $data = array(); 

    if(in_array('application/json', $contentType)) { 
      $data = json_decode($rawBody);
      $total = $data->total;
    } else {
      parse_str($data, $data); 
    }

    include 'apiRedsys.php';

    $miObj = new RedsysAPI;

    // Valores de entrada
    $merchantCode   ="xxx";
    $terminal       ="1";
    $amount         =$total;
    $currency       ="978";
    $transactionType ="0";
    $merchantURL    =""; 
    $urlOK          =""; 
    $urlKO          =""; 
    $order          =time();

    $urlPago = "https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago";

    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER",strval($order));
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE",$merchantCode);
    (...)

    $version="HMAC_SHA256_V1";
    $key = 'xxx';

    $request = "";
    $params = $miObj->createMerchantParameters();
    $signature = $miObj->createMerchantSignature($key);

?>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="frm" action=" <?php echo $urlPago ?>" method="POST" target="_blank" id="sabadell">
Ds_Merchant_SignatureVersion <input type="text" name="Ds_SignatureVersion" value="<?php echo $version; ?>"/></br>
Ds_Merchant_MerchantParameters <input type="text" name="Ds_MerchantParameters" value="<?php echo $params; ?>"/></br>
Ds_Merchant_Signature <input type="text" name="Ds_Signature" value="<?php echo $signature; ?>" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('sabadell').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How could I manage to trigger this form and thus redirecting the user to the desired payment solution website?

Comment: What for are you trying to make an AJAX request here? If they provide a form, then they probably want a client to submit it, and not to have your server make the request. For the latter you should rather look for an API provided for such a use case.

Comment: @CBroe the form includes technical data for the transfer between original website and bank website, is not for the user, but the doc is done like this...

Comment: If the data is sensitive in the way that the user must not know it, then why would they give such a bad example? Anyway, in that case you don't want to "trigger the form" at all, but make the request using PHP to begin with. But that is something you should do some research on first.

Comment: But if I were you I'd double-check if it is even supposed to work this way first ... if this relies on any client-side cookies (not necessarily from your app, but the other domain) or might require the user to present credentials, you're likely not gonna get very far trying to do this from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to post form data to API, if possible

Create hidden form input elements dynamically in your controller to post data and after submission , it will redirect to desired payment interface automatically.

```
var path = $urlPago // post URL (action url)

var params = [{ 'Ds_SignatureVersion' : $version },
              { 'Ds_MerchantParameters' : $params },
              { 'Ds_Signature' : $signature },]  //<========= this contains list of key value of form

function _redirect(path, params, method) {
            method = method || "POST"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

            // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
            // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", method);
            form.setAttribute("action", path);

            for(var key in params) {
                if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
                    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                }
            }
            console.error(form);
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
```